# Inside (cursor) quotes sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, quotes, double-quotes

The only thing I can find on this issue is moving the cursor OUT of the quotes but my problem is this: Whenever I try to type '' or "" i can only type 2 of those, with double tapping the key for it on my keyboard. Then after the '' "" is typed my cursor is ''HERE and ""HERE, not inside.

I have searched on google regarding this problem, opened up a ton of websites only to find a solution for getting it outside of the quotes.

Can someone please give me a name of a plugin or tell me what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. If `|` is your cursor, when you type `"` it looks like `"|`, and when you type `""` it looks like `""|`. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for answering mate. You got the last part right, but not the first part. I can't write a single "(i have erased the other one right now) only like this (holding shift and tapping the button 2 times) ""

Comment: To be more clear, when I press Shift + " Button I get nothing(blank) when I do another click on " i get "". 

When I press Shift + " once and start typing i get this ë

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your keyboard and operating system, not Sublime.

Comment: Thanks for awaring me on that. I did a quick google research and hopefully I fixed it when I restart my computer.